# Why do I see analytics logs in my flutter release app when I haven't added any such dependency?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Why do I see analytics logs in my flutter release app when I haven't added any such dependency. Is this because of transitive dependencies?
Or this really related to analytics at all?

Here is the log which I got in release mode:

```
E/flutter (22994): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'api.tatadigital.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
E/flutter (22994): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682)
E/flutter (22994): #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1827)
E/flutter (22994): #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27)
E/flutter (22994): #3      RawSecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:299)
E/flutter (22994): #4      SecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:77)
E/flutter (22994): #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2449)
E/flutter (22994): #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2867)
E/flutter (22994): #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2872)
E/flutter (22994): #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2727)
E/flutter (22994): #9      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2591)
E/flutter (22994): #10     IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:35)
E/flutter (22994): #11     BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93)
E/flutter (22994): #12     BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32)
E/flutter (22994): #13     post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69)
E/flutter (22994): #14     _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164)
E/flutter (22994): #15     post (package:http/http.dart:68)
E/flutter (22994): #16     AnalyticsApi._fireAnalyticsApi (package:api_core/api/analytics_api.dart:109)
E/flutter (22994): #17     AnalyticsApi._fireEvents.<anonymous closure> (package:api_core/api/analytics_api.dart:68)
E/flutter (22994): #18     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617)
E/flutter (22994): #19     AnalyticsApi._fireEvents (package:api_core/api/analytics_api.dart:65)
E/flutter (22994): #20     AnalyticsApi.report (package:api_core/api/analytics_api.dart:47)
E/flutter (22994): #21     SharedContext.reportSessionStart (package:native_bridge/channel_handlers/shared_context.dart:67)
E/flutter (22994): <asynchronous suspension>
```

And here is the list of packages that I use:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.13.3
  provider: ^6.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  html: ^0.15.0
  html_unescape: ^2.0.0
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.2.0-nullsafety.0
  fl_chart: ^0.45.0
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  scroll_to_index: ^2.0.0
  share: ^2.0.1
  built_collection: ^5.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.3.2
  timezone: ^0.8.0
  flutter_web_browser: ^0.17.0
  flex_color_picker: ^2.3.0
  translator: ^0.1.6
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+1
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0
  retry: ^3.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3
  easy_image_viewer: ^1.1.0
```

*Please note that I didn't see any such log in debug mode*

Comment: It doesn't look like analytic, rather the StackTrace of an error.

Comment: `AnalyticsApi._fireAnalyticsApi` what about this method call?

Comment: Yes, the error may pass through an analytics dependency, but the point is that the console prompt you posted shows an error occurring, not analytics being used/printed.

Comment: Ok, So this error doesn't necessarily mean an analytics dependecy being used. Thanks for looking into it :)